# Button Background image won't shrink in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, image, stretch

I used the following code in a VB.Net forms application:

```
    Dim btnShowHideSize As New Size(30, 30)
    btnShowHide.Size = btnShowHideSize
    Dim img As New Bitmap(Resources.change2)
    Dim img2 As New Bitmap(img, btnShowHideSize)
    btnShowHide.BackgroundImage = img2
    btnShowHide.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
```

The image will expand, but not shrink. When I step through, I see that img size is 80,80 and img2 size is 30,30.  Howewver, the image is not shrinking - it is getting cut off.  If I go above 80,80 e.g. 200,200, the image does expand.

Is shrinking an image not possible?

Comment: Why don't you try sizing the button instead of the image?

Comment: I did.  I tried various sizes as mentioned in my post.  But ultimately I want the button to be 30x30.

Comment: What I am saying is don't assign any size to the image. Just the button and the image will resize itself to fit.

Comment: Thanx @decyclone That is what I had initially.  I just assigned it through the properties sidebar - it didn't work either as image or as background image.  Then I blanked out the value in the properties sidebar and assigned it in the code.

    btnShowHide.BackgroundImage = Resources.change2
    btnShowHide.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch

That didn't work either, and that is when I tried all this fancy code above.  I don't know how to do a new line in this but each line starting with btnShowHide is a new line.